# Cannot deserialize java.time.Month using Jackson 2.11.0

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am having a heck of a time trying to deserialize a field of type 'java.time.Month'.

To use the simplest example possible, attempting to deserialize just a plain old Month fails as follows:
Code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
objectMapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule());

Month month = objectMapper.readValue("{\"month\":\"OCTOBER\"}", java.time.Month.class);
```

Results in the following error:

```
Invalid type definition for type `java.time.Month`: Argument #0 has no property name, is not
Injectable: can not use as Creator [method java.time.Month#valueOf(1 params)]
 at [Source: (String)"{"month":"OCTOBER"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type 
`java.time.Month`: Argument #0 has no property name, is not Injectable: can not use as Creator 
[method java.time.Month#valueOf(1 params)]
 at [Source: (String)"{"month":"OCTOBER"}"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I have attempted various solutions that are suggested online, but I am stumped by this.  I will note that I can successfully deserialize fields with OTHER built in time datatypes such as java.time.MonthDay.

According to Oracle's Java 8 docs, Month is Serializable.
I would appreciate any and all help. I am stumped.  Thank you!

Here are my relevant gradle deps:

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.0'
api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.11.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.11.0'
```

Edit:  I think my example was oversimplified.  Here is the actual class, and the json string produced by ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString() for my class:

```
@Value
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnnualDateRule extends DateRule
{
    String name;
    Month     month;
    DayOfWeek targetDayOfWeek;

    @Min(value = 1)
    @Max(value = 5)
    int       nthOccurrence;
}
```

String produced by ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString():

```
{"className":"AnnualDateRule","name":"Test Rule","month":"OCTOBER","targetDayOfWeek":"MONDAY","nthOccurrence":3}
```

Error message when attempting to deserialize that string:

```
Invalid type definition for type `java.time.Month`: Argument #0 has no property name, is not Injectable: can not use as Creator [method java.time.Month#from(1 params)]
 at [Source: (String)"{"className":"AnnualDateRule","name":"Test Rule","month":"OCTOBER","targetDayOfWeek":"MONDAY","nthOccurrence":3}"; line: 1, column: 14]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `java.time.Month`: Argument #0 has no property name, is not Injectable: can not use as Creator [method java.time.Month#from(1 params)]
 at [Source: (String)"{"className":"AnnualDateRule","name":"Test Rule","month":"OCTOBER","targetDayOfWeek":"MONDAY","nthOccurrence":3}"; line: 1, column: 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked Jackson to deserialize the JSON as a `Month`, but you didn't provide *a Month value*: Instead, you provided *a JSON object with a property whose value is a Month*.

The JSON that you provided would match this class:

```java
class MyObj {
  Month month
}
```

Or, you can deserialize the JSON `"OCTOBER"` as a `Month`.

In the future, try serializing a value using `writeValueAsString` to compare its structure when it seems you have a mismatch; that would have immediately shown you the difference.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to respond.  I think that I did not correctly simplify my sample.  I did the steps you describe with my code where I first encountered the problem.  And btw the string I provide is the string that was provided by the serialize function.  This is my class:
`@Value
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnnualDateRule extends DateRule
{
 String name;
 Month     month;
 DayOfWeek targetDayOfWeek;}`
Sorry for the terrible formatting.